# Amazon EMR and Yarn deployment mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am learning Spark fundamentals and in order to test my Pyspark application created an EMR instance with Spark, Yarn, Hadoop, Oozie on AWS. I am successfully able to execute a simple pyspark application from the driver node using spark-submit. I have the default /etc/spark/conf/spark-default.conf file created by AWS which is using Yarn Resource Manager. Everything runs fine and I can monitor the Tracking URL as well.
But I am not able to differentiate between whether the spark job is running in 'client' mode or 'cluster' mode. How do I determine that?

Excerpts from /etc/spark/conf/spark-default.conf

```
spark.master                     yarn                                                                                                            
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native                                                       
spark.executor.extraClassPath    :/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar    
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.sql.warehouse.dir          hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse
spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2
spark.yarn.historyServer.address ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal:18080 
spark.history.ui.port            18080
spark.shuffle.service.enabled    true 
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled true
spark.sql.emr.internal.extensions com.amazonaws.emr.spark.EmrSparkSessionExtensions                                                              
spark.executor.memory            4743M                                                                                                           
spark.executor.cores             2                                                                                                               
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverheadFactor 0.1875
spark.driver.memory              2048M
```

Excerpts from my pypspark job:

```
import os.path
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf   
from boto3.session import Session 

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MyFirstPySparkApp')
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext 
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_KEY) 
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
....# access S3 bucket
....
....
```

Is there a deployment mode called 'yarn-client' or is it just 'client' and 'cluster'?
Also, why is "num-executors" not specified in the config file by AWS? Is that something I need to add?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It is determined by how you send the option when you submit the job, see the [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#launching-spark-on-yarn).

Once you access to the spark history server from the EMR console or by web server, you can find the `spark.submit.deployMode` option in the Environment tab. In my case, it is client mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default spark application runs in client mode, i.e. driver runs on the node where you're submitting the application from. Details about these deployment configurations can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html). One easy to verify it would be to kill the running process by pressing ctrl + c on terminal after the job goes to *RUNNING* state. If it's running on *client* mode, the app would die. If it's running in *cluster* mode it would continue to run, because the driver is running in one of the worker nodes in EMR cluster. A sample spark-submit command to run the job in *cluster* mode would be

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--py-files my-dependencies.zip \
--num-executors 10 \
--executor-cores 2 \
--executor-memory 5g \
--name sample-pyspark \
--deploy-mode cluster \
package.pyspark.main
```

By default number of executors is set to 1. You can check the default values for all spark configs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).